# Python tkinter on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

This is a very basic question. I'm reading the book 'Programming Python' and following the tutorial. But the book is based on the Windows, and I'm doing in Mac, and the result seems different.

Code is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror
import shelve
shelvename='class-shelve'
fieldnames=('name','age','job','pay')

def makeWidgets():
    global entries
    window=Tk()
    window.title('People Shelve')
    form=Frame(window)
    form.pack()
    entries={}
    for (ix,label) in enumerate(('key',)+fieldnames):
        lab=Label(form,text=label)
        ent=Entry(form)
        lab.grid(row=ix,column=0)
        lab.grid(row=ix,column=1)
        entries[label]=ent
    Button(window,text="Fetch",command=fetchRecord).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(window,text="Update",command=updateRecord).pack(side=LEFT)
    Button(window,text="Quit",command=window.quit).pack(side=RIGHT)
    return window

def fetchRecord():
    key=entries['key'].get()
    try:
        record=db[key]
    except:
        showerror(title='Error',message='No such key!')
    else:
        for field in fieldnames:
            entries[field].delete(0,END)
            entries[field].insert(0,repr(getattr(record,field)))

def updateRecord():
    key=entries['key'].get()
    if key in db:
        record=db[key]
    else:
        from person import Person
        record=Person(name='?',age='?')
    for field in fieldnames:
        setattr(record, field, eval(entries[field].get()))
    db[key]=record

db=shelve.open(shelvename)
window=makeWidgets()
window.mainloop()
db.close()
```

And the book says the result should look like:

[image]

But it does look like in my Mac:

[image]
So there is no space for me to type something.

How can I fix it?

Comment: For one, call the `grid` method on the entries.

Comment: You miscopied the code from the book - you have `lab.grid()` twice, the second one should be `ent.grid()`.

Comment: @jasonharper O thanks. I think I made the mistake cuz I dont understand the code.